# MySQL Nested aggregation query with selection of specific intermediate items

Tags: sql, mariadb, window-functions, mariadb-10.5

This is my `activities` table.

```
activities
+----+---------+----------+-----------------+
| id | user_id | activity |    log_time     |
+----+---------+----------+-----------------+
|  6 |       1 | start    | 12 Oct, 1000hrs |
|  2 |       1 | task     | 12 Oct, 1010hrs |
|  7 |       1 | task     | 12 Oct, 1040hrs |
|  3 |       1 | start    | 12 Oct, 1600hrs |
|  1 |       1 | task     | 12 Oct, 1610hrs |
|  9 |       1 | start    | 14 Oct, 0800hrs |
| 10 |       1 | start    | 16 Oct, 0900hrs |
|  4 |       1 | task     | 16 Oct, 0910hrs |
|  8 |       2 | start    | 12 Oct, 1000hrs |
|  5 |       2 | task     | 12 Oct, 1020hrs |
+----+---------+----------+-----------------+
```

and I need the total time spent by the user across all sessions. Each session happens within a day and includes a 'start' and multiple 'tasks' (before the next session is initiated with a 'start'). A session duration = last task - start [the timestamp difference]

```
output
+---------+------------+------------------------------------------------+
| user_id | total_time |       This is explanation (not a column)       |
+---------+------------+------------------------------------------------+
|       1 |         60 | 12_Oct[40+10] + 14_Oct[0] + 16_Oct[10] = 60min |
|       2 |         20 | 12_Oct[20]  = 20min                            |
+---------+------------+------------------------------------------------+
```

I am unable to figure out how to get the last task in a session. I have tried the basic aggregation and join queries - but it doesn't work.

As an approach, what I think I really need is to get the last column (below / session_group) somehow, and then I can aggregate and get the difference between max/min timestamp.

```
+----+---------+----------+-----------------+---------------+
| id | user_id | activity |    log_time     | session_group |
+----+---------+----------+-----------------+---------------+
|  6 |       1 | start    | 12 Oct, 1000hrs |             1 |
|  2 |       1 | task     | 12 Oct, 1010hrs |             1 |
|  7 |       1 | task     | 12 Oct, 1040hrs |             1 |
|  3 |       1 | start    | 12 Oct, 1600hrs |             2 |
|  1 |       1 | task     | 12 Oct, 1610hrs |             2 |
|  9 |       1 | start    | 14 Oct, 0800hrs |             3 |
| 10 |       1 | start    | 16 Oct, 0900hrs |             4 |
|  4 |       1 | task     | 16 Oct, 0910hrs |             4 |
|  8 |       2 | start    | 12 Oct, 1000hrs |             5 |
|  5 |       2 | task     | 12 Oct, 1020hrs |             5 |
+----+---------+----------+-----------------+---------------+
```

Please let me know if it is even possible to get the desired output via sql (MySQL) and how to go about it ? Or is it necessary to loop through the data via say Javascript ?

Below is the MySQL query for the tables:

```
create table activities (
  id INT NOT NULL, 
  user_id INT NULL, 
  activity VARCHAR(45), 
  log_time DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  PRIMARY KEY(id))
 ENGINE = InnoDB;    
 
insert into activities
    (id, user_id, activity, log_time) 
values
    (6,1,'start', '2021-10-12 10:00:00'), 
    (2,1,'task' , '2021-10-12 10:10:00'), 
    (7,1,'task' , '2021-10-12 10:40:00'), 
    (3,1,'start', '2021-10-12 16:00:00'), 
    (1,1,'task',  '2021-10-12 16:10:00'), 
    (9,1,'task',  '2021-10-14 08:00:00'), 
    (10,1,'start','2021-10-16 09:00:00'), 
    (4,1,'task',  '2021-10-16 09:10:00'), 
    (8,2,'start', '2021-10-12 10:00:00'), 
    (5,2,'task',  '2021-10-12 10:20:00');
```

Comment: which mysql version are you using?

Comment: 10.5.10-MariaDB-1:10.5.10+maria~focal

Comment: What is the correct activity for id=9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUM()` window function to assign a number to each session and then aggregate:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id,
       SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(log_time), MAX(log_time))) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id) total_time 
FROM (
  SELECT *, SUM(activity = 'start') OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, DATE(log_time) ORDER BY log_time) grp
  FROM activities
) t
WHERE grp > 0
GROUP BY user_id, DATE(log_time), grp;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=0e90e142d24ea5f0a4f48d0d23fe0696).

Answer (score 1):

This might work. Find all start-task pairs and take the maximum difference in minutes, then sum up the minutes for each user.

```
select user_id, sum(minutes) minutes
from (
    select a.user_id, a.id, max(timestampdiff(minute, a.log_time, b.log_time)) minutes
    from activities a 
    join activities b on a.user_id = b.user_id and a.log_time < b.log_time 
    where a.activity = 'start'
    and b.activity = 'task'
    and date(a.log_time) = date(b.log_time)
    and not exists (
      select 1
      from activities c 
      where c.user_id = a.user_id
      and a.activity = c.activity
      and c.log_time > a.log_time
      and c.log_time < b.log_time
    )
    group by a.user_id, a.id   
) f
group by user_id
```

or using window functions

```
with combo as
(
select user_id, activity, log_time,
 lag(activity) over( partition by user_id  order by log_time) last_activity,
 lag(log_time) over( partition by user_id  order by log_time) last_log_time
from activities
)
select user_id, sum(timestampdiff(minute, last_log_time, log_time))
from combo
where activity = 'task'
and date(log_time) = date(last_log_time)
group by user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table activities (
   id INT NOT NULL, 
   user_id INT NULL, 
   activity VARCHAR(45), 
   log_time DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
   PRIMARY KEY(id))
  ENGINE = InnoDB;    
  
 insert into activities
     (id, user_id, activity, log_time) 
 values
     (6,1,'start', '2021-10-12 10:00:00'), 
     (2,1,'task' , '2021-10-12 10:10:00'), 
     (7,1,'task' , '2021-10-12 10:40:00'), 
     (3,1,'start', '2021-10-12 16:00:00'), 
     (1,1,'task',  '2021-10-12 16:10:00'), 
     (9,1,'start',  '2021-10-14 08:00:00'), 
     (10,1,'start','2021-10-16 09:00:00'), 
     (4,1,'task',  '2021-10-16 09:10:00'), 
     (8,2,'start', '2021-10-12 10:00:00'), 
     (5,2,'task',  '2021-10-12 10:20:00');
```

Query:

```
 with tasks as
 (
 SELECT
   user_id, partition_condition ,TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute,min(log_time),max(log_time))time_diff
 FROM (
   SELECT
     id, user_id, activity, log_time,
     sum(case when activity='start' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by user_id order by log_time) as partition_condition
 
   FROM activities
 
 ) as tasks
 group by user_id, partition_condition
 )
 select user_id,sum(time_diff)total_time from tasks
 group by user_id
```

Output:

| user_id | total_time |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 60 |
| 2 | 20 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=b4c67dc17115346fe2859adf779d48bc)*

Comment: @forpas thanks for the notification. I have changed my logic but forgot to remove the line. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can proceed for each **user** and **day** along with **LAG()** window function in order to compute the minute differences for each row with ***task*** activity such as

```sql
SELECT user_id, 
       SUM( TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, COALESCE( lg, log_time ), log_time ) ) AS total_time
  FROM (SELECT LAG(log_time) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, DATE(log_time) 
                                      ORDER BY log_time) AS lg, 
               a.*
          FROM activities AS a
         ORDER BY log_time) AS aa
  WHERE activity != 'start'      
  GROUP BY user_id
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=1099117df4117a264d0c413c2b549e62)</kbd>